# What are some free streaming services besides Crunchyroll which stream English Dubbed shows?

Tags: resources

According to my information, Crunchyroll provides streams of anime and is legal. It has tons of anime, most of them are only english subbed. The biggest issue regarding Crunchyroll is that most of the anime are not available in all regions of the world.

I would like to know the names of a few free alternatives to Crunchyroll which have English dubbed anime and are legal.

Comment: several resources are listed on this answer but I can't guarentee they will have what you want.  http://meta.anime.stackexchange.com/questions/922/how-can-i-tell-if-a-site-is-legal?lq=1

Comment: Is there any region in particular that you might be interested in? Answers may different by locale. (For instance, Hulu has been suggested---and it indeed contains anime dubs---but IIRC it's only available in the US.)

Comment: As @Maroon stated, your question implies that your issue with Crunchyroll is partly because of some region-locking. In that case, it's important to know what region you're in so we can tag your question as such, and provide answers specific to that region. From what I know, there's not going to be a lot of free English dubbed streams available.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To stream a dubbed anime legally in a given region, you need to have the appropriate licence. The problem is that if you want to stream something across 10 countries, you will potentially need to arrange for 10 licences because the original producer (which would generally be a company in the US) may have arrangements with a different company in each of the 10 countries for that company to have the local distribution rights. It might be a bit different if (a) the US company has local subsidiaries in those companies or (b) there is no local licencee and the original producer is then the default license-holder - in both cases you can arrange with the parent company to licence off all of those regions together.

In any case, the end result is that out of (1) has a large range of shows, (2) lets you watch the shows in all regions, and (3) is legally allowed to stream the shows, you get to pick two. Also, licencing costs money, so odds are that if you want something that offers shows for free (especially the newest stuff) then you almost certainly aren't looking for something legal.

For most regions, CrunchyRoll is still going to be your go-to. They do mostly have subs, but for some older series they have dubs as either an alternative or the only option, and while not everything is available in all regions it's still a pretty good offering. Netflix is now available in many countries, and in at least some of those countries it has a sizeable anime selection, at least some of which is dubbed. Otherwise, you'll probably have to look for something specific to where you are, possibly run by a local distributor. For example, here in Australia both MadMan and Hanabee have some series streamable on their respective websites, and MadMan also set up AnimeLab as a kind of local Crunchyroll.

Answer (score 8):

MyAnimeList compiled a list of [The 18 Best International Sites to Legally Stream Anime](http://myanimelist.net/featured/1617). They do mention a few that offer dubs (and they mention Crunchyroll offers *some* dubbed titles), and they also mention the region availability. Not all of them are free, but most of these will offer at least *some* free content:

- [Funimation](http://www.funimation.com/), Availability: US and Canada
- [AnimeLab](https://www.animelab.com/home), Availability: Australia and New Zealand
- [Hanabee](http://hanabee.tv/), Availability: Australia and New Zealand
- [Hulu](http://www.hulu.com/tv/genres/anime), Availability: US
- [Amazon](http://www.amazon.com/gp/search/ref=sr_hi_2?rh=n%3A2858778011%2Cp_n_theme_browse-bin%3A2650364011&bbn=2858778011&ie=UTF8&qid=1460709393), Availability: Global
- [The Anime Network](http://www.theanimenetwork.com/), Availability: NA and UK
- [Animax TV](http://www.animaxtv.co.uk/), Availability: UK and Ireland
- [Manga Entertainment](http://www.manga.com/titles), Availability: UK and US
- [MyAnimeList](http://myanimelist.net/), Availability: Global (dependent on title)
- [Anime Serien](http://www.anime-serien.com/), Availability: Global (note: this site is not a streaming site, but rather one that helps you locate legal streams for anime subbed/dubbed in various European languages)